# Find the $p_{Y|X}(y|x)$ without the jointly probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let the distribution $Y = X + N$. Where $X$ and $N$ are independents and they have distinct distributions.

I have $f_X(x)$ but I don't have the $f_{XY}(x,y)$ to use, for example, the following equation:

$$
   f_{Y|X}(y|x) = \frac{f_{XY}(x,y)}{f_X(x)}
$$
Moreover, I have the characteristic functions of $X$ and $N$.
How can I find the conditional probability $f_{Y|X}(y|x)$? 
What are the approaches that I can try? 
Is it possible to use the correlation between the distributions to find the conditional probability?

Comment: Do you have $f_{N}(n)$?

Comment: yes, I have the $f_N(n)$.

Comment: $f_{Y|X}(y|x) = \frac{f_{XY(x,y)}}{f_{X}(x)} = \frac{f_{Y}(y)}{f_{X}(x)}. f_{X|Y}(x|y) $

Comment: Or may be you can replace $f_{XY}(x,y)$ by $f_{N}(y-x)$. But I'm not sure.

Comment: you are right!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: as $Y=X+N$ then $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_{X,N}(x, y-x) \\ = f_X(x)\;f_N(y-x)$

So ...$$f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x) = f_N(y-x)$$

Comment: really thanks. My problem was the notation to change Y by N.